SQL query with no space after question mark
is it possible to run this query
jdbcTemplate.update(
           "UPDATE SOME_TABLE SET  MY_NAME=?,MY_FILE=?" +
                  "WHERE MY_ID = ?", 
           new Object[] {
               "TestME",null,ID
                   
               });

Note that there is no space between the 2nd ? and WHERE keyword.
I can add a space in between and make it run but we have such instance in many places so wanted to check if we can avoid code changes

If you use Java 15 or later, you can use text blocks instead of needing to concatenate pieces of strings. See examples here: https://openjdk.org/jeps/378

No, it is not possible. The space is required to separate the parameter from the WHERE. Fix your code. It should be simple with a find and replace. Search for "WHERE and replace with " WHERE.

Well, why don't you test it?
My test in plain JDBC shows a valid statement. I'm using Groovy script with JDBC, but assume that the same behaviour will occure in  jdbcTemplate. The SQL string is important.
SQL = "UPDATE SOME_TABLE SET  MY_NAME=?,MY_FILE=?" +
                  "WHERE MY_ID = ?"
println SQL                  
def stmt = cn.prepareStatement(SQL)

stmt.setString(1,'x')
stmt.setString(2,'y')
stmt.setInt(3,1)                  
Integer rowCount = stmt.executeUpdate()
println "update rowCount= $rowCount "

the output is
UPDATE SOME_TABLE SET  MY_NAME=?,MY_FILE=?WHERE MY_ID = ?
update rowCount= 1

And by the way SQL realy do not requires blank separators in each possition. This is also a valid statement.
 UPDATE SOME_TABLE SET  MY_NAME='xx',MY_FILE='yy'WHERE MY_ID = 1;

Tested in PostgreSQL 14.4
